# reordering geom_bar when using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I try to achieve is having the bars ordered by a given variable per panel.

A simple example:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plyr)

    df <- data.frame(fac = c("a", "b", "c", "e", "b", "c", "d"),             
                  val = c(1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 1),
                  group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))

    p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = fac, y = val)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free") + coord_flip()
    p1

    p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(fac, val), y = val)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free") + coord_flip()
    p2
```

p2 does not produce what I want because not every "factor level" appears in all panels. Is there a simple solution already for this problem?

One solution I found is the following (calculates the rank for each factor level per group).

```
df2 <- ddply(df, .(group), transform, fac2 = rank(val))
df2$fac2 <- factor(df2$fac2)
p3 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = fac2, y = val)) + facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free") + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
  opts(panel.margin = unit(2, "lines"))
p3
```

I have to set the labels by my self here. One possible solution is the following (hard coded for this example):

```
grid.newpage()
grob <- ggplotGrob(p3)
object.path <- grid.ls(getGrob(grob, "axis.text.y", grep = TRUE, global = TRUE), print = FALSE)$name
grob <- grid::editGrob(grob, object.path[1], label = c("ABDQ", "M", "A", "B"))
grob <- grid::editGrob(grob, object.path[2], label = c("A", "B", "EEEEX"))
grid.draw(grob)
```

But there is another problem. I have to set the panel.margin by my self now and it seems to be not possible to do this as I'm only able to set a "global" panel.margin and what I need is one for all 4 sides (or at least 2).

Question 1: Is there a simple solution using reorder?

Question 2: Is there a solution using scale_x_discrete to get the needed axis?

Question 3: I wasn't able to find the needed grid object to manipulate the viewports for the panel.margins. Is there an easy way to manipulate the appropriate grid object?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `grid.arrange` is a much better tool for this than trying to shoehorn free scales into a faceting framework:

```
library(gridExtra)
q1 <- ggplot(subset(df,group == 1),aes(x = reorder(fac,val),y = val)) + 
        geom_bar() + 
        facet_wrap(~group) + 
        coord_flip()

q2 <- q1 %+% subset(df,group == 2)

grid.arrange(q1,q2,nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of grid.arrange.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks.