# Reorder facet_grid and factor in ggplot2’s geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems getting the corrector order of factors within a barplot.

I have a dataset with three variables: `Region`, `Store.Type`, and `Avg.Value`. `Region` and `Store.Type` are factor types and `Avg.Value` is a numeric. I am using the `ggplot2` plotting system in R in a bar chart format with the `geom_bar()` function.

**Desired result:**
I want Supercenter to be the first category in the `facet_grid()` followed by the Market, and Mart. Within each facet, I want `Region` 1-7 sorted by descending order by `Avg.Value`.

**Reproducible example:**
There are 3 `Store.Type` for every `Region` making a total of 21 `Avg.Value` observations. My original dataset is larger with >3k observations.

```
#Create dataset
#avg value
Avg.Value <- as.vector(as.numeric(1:21))
#Regions
ab <- c("Region 1","Region 2","Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 5", "Region 6", "Region 7")
b <- 3 # Or some other number
ab <- sapply(ab, function (x) rep(x,b))
Region <- as.vector(ab)
#Chains
Store.Type <- c("Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", 
                "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market",
                "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market",
                "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market")
#Combine dataset
avgRes <- data.frame(Avg.Value, Region, Store.Type)
#Graph
library(ggplot2)
ch <- ggplot(avgRes, aes(x = Region, y = Avg.Value))
cha <- ch + geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
chan <- cha + facet_grid(. ~ Store.Type) 
chang <- chan + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
chang + ggtitle("Chart")
```

**Barchart:**

[image]

**EDIT: I also want a count legend with the blue shading.**

Comment: these posts should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262497/fixing-the-order-of-facets-in-ggplot and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238687/r-reorder-facet-wrapped-x-axis-with-free-x-in-ggplot2

Comment: The first link helped fix the ordering of the facet_grid() by converting the categorical variables of Store.Type as ordinal. I do not know how to make each category of Region in descending order. Both links suggest setting the order beforehand, but the ranking of Region differs for each Store.Type.

Comment: You can make a ranking variable and order your data by that.

Comment: @Heroka I cannot make a ranking variable for Region. The data that I posted is not the same as the actual. The ranking for Region will be different for each facet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I have done is flipped the second range in your dataset, 
otherwise the regions would always be in order 1 to 7 and you can't tell if it works.

```
#Create dataset avg value 
Avg.Value <- as.vector(as.numeric(c(1:7,14:8,15:21)))
#Regions
ab <- c("Region 1","Region 2","Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 5", "Region 6", "Region 7")
b <- 3 # Or some other number
ab <- sapply(ab, function (x) rep(x,b))
Region <- as.vector(ab)
#Chains
Store.Type <- c("Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", 
                "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market",
                "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market", "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market",
                "Supercenter", "Mart", "Market")
#Combine dataset
avgRes <- data.frame(Avg.Value, Region, Store.Type)
```

Then we need to reorder the levels of avgRes$Store.Type

```
avgRes$Store.Type <- factor(avgRes$Store.Type, levels = c("Supercenter", "Market", "Mart"))
```

The next problem is that ggplot can't split the order of Region for each facet, so we will have to add a unique order variable. After that, we can reorder using that variable. This has been taken from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238687/r-reorder-facet-wrapped-x-axis-with-free-x-in-ggplot2).

```
avgRes$ordvar <- paste(avgRes$Store.Type,avgRes$Region,sep="_")

#Graph
library(ggplot2)
ch <- ggplot(avgRes, aes(x = reorder(ordvar,Avg.Value), y = Avg.Value)) # reorder ordvar by value
cha <- ch + geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
chan <- cha + facet_grid(. ~ Store.Type, scale="free_x") #added "free_x", or you will have a lot of blank values in your plot
chang <- chan + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
chang + ggtitle("Chart")
```

[image]

Notice that the labels are now Store.Type_Region. 
  If that bothers you, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238687/r-reorder-facet-wrapped-x-axis-with-free-x-in-ggplot2) how to fix that with a function.